# 'llvm/IR/Constants.h' file not found

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-clang

I'm trying to make a compiler and I'm using **llvm (C++ api)** for intermediate and final code production. Though when trying to execute the command:

```
llvm.o: llvm.cpp llvm.h
    $(CPP) llvm.cpp -c -$(FLAGS)
```

in my make file I'm getting the error:

```
In file included from llvm.cpp:6:
./opt.h:5:10: fatal error: 'llvm/IR/Constants.h' file not found
#include <llvm/IR/Constants.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

I'm using **Mac Os (Sierra version 10.12.6)** and I've installed llvm using brew (`brew install llvm`) so I can't understand how the library file can't be found.

Also my **clang version**:

```
bash-3.2$ clang --version
Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.37)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

I've googled it a lot but couldn't find anything that solve my problem, any help appreciated !!!.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What're your FLAGS? You would need to provide linker flags and header search flags.

The following could help you:

```
llvm.o: llvm.cpp llvm.h
    $(CPP) llvm.cpp -c -$(FLAGS) `llvm-config --cxxflags --ldflags --libs`
```

Note that the `--libs` without any parameters will link your binary with all the LLVM libraries.

**UPD:**

On MacOS llvm-config and other tools are not added to the `$PATH`, because it would override system compiler and can screw your system in some way. You would need to use the full path, e.g. `/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/3.9.0/bin/llvm-config`. Make sure you use the right version here.

Also, make sure that your FLAGS are actually evaluated and not pasted to the command as is:

```
FLAGS=$(shell llvm-config --cxxflags --ldflags --libs)
```

Comment: Thanks for response, my flags: `llvm-config-3.8 --cxxflags --ldflags --libs  --system-libs` but also another problem that I didn't mentioned is that it doesn't recognize ` llvm-config-3.8 --cxxflags` e.g the message I'm getting `/bin/bash: llvm-config-3.8: command not found` but I didn't mentioned about the flags since I thought the main problem was the library missing...

Comment: Many Thanks :) !!! You had right the problem was the path,  I still get some errors due to version off llvm I'm using (5.0.0) but you answer solves 100% my original/ first problem !!!